# Networking game with HTML5, Javascript, and AJAX. Would this work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, networking

I'm currently building my first website just for practice. I threw together a quick game of pong in HTML5 and javascript. I was wondering how I could go about turning it into a networked game.

Is there anything stopping me from say, logging a user into my site, storing their information in a sql database, then looking for another person logged in and waiting to play my game. To handle the networking could I just create a sql database and use AJAX to post new information to a table that specifically handles networking?

here's a visual example of what i've been brainstorming:

```
  [sql table: network]
  [logged in user: Josh] [Josh paddle position Y]
  [logged in user: Tim] [Tim Paddle position Y]

  Use Ajax XMLHttpRequest to post Josh paddle position Y and Tim Paddle Position Y
  to the network table, updating each client's screen accordingly (maybe use XMLHttpRequest.responseText to get the other person's information)

  delete network table when both users have left the game
```

Anyway if you don't think this method would work, could you point me in the right direction maybe? I'm still very new to web programming, so maybe i've miss understood the way Ajax works. How is networking normally done when it comes to web applications?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. Can you update paddle position as fast as user moves it? Network communication have lags, DB requires time to update it's data.
2. Even if for few users it isn't such a problem, for many people it will become really painfull to handle with all this amount of user's requests.
3. How do you notify one user about another one actions? In your scheme you should ask server very frequently to get updates. This increases overall load.

The solution could be a peer-to-peer connection, but JS doesn't support it for now.

To post updates and get notified about them you can use persistent connection: instead of reestabilishing connection on each query you just do it once and then use it for bidirectional communication. Additional benefit from this is escape from need of polling server about updates.
See a [Server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_push) article on Wikipedia.

Also using DB may be unresonably costly. In fact for each game all you need is several variables that will be deleted when connection will close, so you can just store them in memory.